# Python - Не работает RSA

Tags: python, шифрование, rsa

Есть мессенджер на Flask. Нужно добавить в него асимитричтое шифрование, при помощи библиотеки RSA.

Шифрую, и передаю так:

```
crypt = rsa.encrypt(text.encode('utf8'), pubkey)
requests.get(address + '/send/' + str(crypt))
```

Расшифровываю так:

```
text = str.encode(text)
text = rsa.decrypt(text, privkey)
```

Но после этого почему-то возникает ошибка:

```
rsa.pkcs1.DecryptionError: Decryption failed
```

Что идет не так?
Если просмотреть зашифрованное сообщение, то оно выглядит так:

```
b"b'1\\xeb\\xef\\xebO\\xec\\x99\\xed\\x98\\xc1\\x05\\xff\\xe3\\xed@\\xaf\\xee&*\\x15\\xcd\\x83\\xd7\\x14Y\\xb931\\x00\\xf4\\nC'"
```

Comment: А зачем encode?

Comment: RSA для расшифровки требует байовый тип, а не строку. encode превращает строку в байтовый тип

Comment: Откуда/как приходит text? Похоже, там уже и есть байтовая строка.

Comment: `str(crypt)` ломает зашифрованный текст

Comment: а как по другому? я не могу соеденить байты со строкой

Comment: Пытаться запихнуть байты в строку адреса — изначально хреновая идея. Почему бы вам не использовать POST-запрос?

Comment: фласк вроде-бы только get запросы поддерживает

Comment: Вас сильно обманули, Flask всегда умел POST-запросы, читайте документацию

Comment: а как байты передавать к запросам?